# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window'

Tags: javascript, api, fetch

Estoy tratando de pasarle clientes a un API (<crudcrud.com>) con fetch pero me salta el error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': The provided value is not of type '(sequence<sequence> or record<ByteString, ByteString>)'at HTMLFormElement. (app.js:48)

Mi código es:

```
    fetch(`${API_URL}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(client) ,
        mode: "cors" ,
        headers: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*' ,
        headers: 'Content-type:application/json'

    })
```

donde *client* es un objeto. ¿Por qué será el error?

Answer (score 1):

No estás armando el objeto `headers` correctamente, con pares *clave: valor*.

```
fetch(`${API_URL}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(client) ,
    mode: "cors" ,
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' ,
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
    }
});
```

Para más información,  consulta [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#suministrando_opciones_de_petici%C3%B3n) de *Mozilla*, que suele estar muy bien explicada y al día.